# Firebase - how to retrieve data only where the user id matches a key in the object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, nosql

I have the following "database" in Firebase:

```
projects: {
  "-KpVHI1za0ElBWIJWb2k": {
     "name": "John's project"
     "uId": "Kojh6pkRNJPBzU78yzNXUiFv3aP2"
  },
  "-KpVHI1zadedldedWIJWb2k": {
     "name": "Kojh6pkRNJPBzU78yzNXUiFv3aP2"
     "uId": "Kojh6pkRNJPBzU78yzNXUiFv3aP2
  },
  "-KpVKKjSnCD3obVW-hsw": {
     "name": "Kojh6pkRNJPBzU78yzNXUiFv3aP2"
     "uId": "KPQgqAniekUhavofb79v2Jqjdwh1"
  }
}
```

Is there  a way using firebase rules to retrieve all the projects that have a specific "uId" value.
For example I have these rules in place but they do not work:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "projects": {
       ".read": "auth != null && data.child('uId').val() == auth.uid",
       ".write": "auth != null" 
    }
  }
}
```

I am doing the following query

```
firebase.database().ref('projects')on('value', (project) => {
        onRequestProject(project)
      }, (error) => {
        onRequestError(error)
      })
```

I looked in the Firebase documentation but there I could not find something to solve this.
The error I receive: "Error: PERMISSION_DENIED".
Any help is welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to read all child objects, but you given rules to read on child object with matching uid.

Try changing the db query to:

```
firebase.database().ref('projects').orderByChild('uId').equalTo(<your_reqd_userId>).on('value', (project) => {
    onRequestProject(project)
  }, (error) => {
    onRequestError(error)
  })
```

If the above method doesn't work, I would suggest you changing the database structure to something like this:

```
"projects": {
    "uid1":{
        Add your child objects here.
    },
    "uid2":{
        Add your child objects here.
    }
}
```

and security rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "projects": {
       "$uId": {
           ".read": "auth.uid === $uId",
           ".write": "auth.uid === $uId"
       }
    }
}
```

And your db query will be:

```
firebase.database().ref('projects').child(<your_reqd_userId>).on('value', (project) => {
    onRequestProject(project)
  }, (error) => {
    onRequestError(error)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you Anand! That solved my question. Very well explained.